# record processing in shell script

Tags: shell

I am writing a shell script to process multiple gz files in a directory.Each file contains multiple records seperated by ------------- an example

A=1

B=2

C=random=1

EOE

---

A=2

B=2

C=random=1,dummy=2

EOE

---

Now my problem is I need to go through all the files and for each record in the file determine the value of A and it its 1 then process that record further otherwise ignore the record and move to next.
If A=1
 then need to determine if the record has value of dummy=2, if it is present increment a counter and finally print the counter on the screen.So in the above example I should print 1.

I am new to linux world so I started with

```
for(file in query*)
 do
    record = //not sure how to get individual record and proceed futher
```

Could someone please explain how to get individual record and then use grep to determine the text and return the count?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that this is our sample gzipped file:

```
$ zcat file.gz
A=1
B=2
C=random=1
-----------
A=2
B=2
C=random=1,dummy=2
------------
A=1
B=2
C=random=1,dummy=2
-----------
```

If we want to count the number of times that a single record contains both `A=1` and `dummy=2`, then use:

```
$ zcat file.gz | awk -v RS="-----------\n" '/A=2[ ,\n]/ && /dummy=2[ ,\n]/{count++} END{print "Final counter value=",count}'
Final counter value= 1
```

#### How it works

- `-v RS="-----------\n"`

  `awk` separates files into records.  Here, we tell it to use a series of dashes as the record separator.
- '/A=2[ ,\n]/ && /dummy=2[ ,\n]/{count++}`

  This statement is executed every time `awk` encounters a new record.  This statement consists of two parts: conditions and commands.  The two conditions are that the record contain `A=1` and `dummy=2`.  If those conditions are met, then the command is executed which increments a counter called `count`.

  More precisely, `/A=2[ ,\n]/` requires that the record contain `A=2` followed by a space, comma, or newline.  This prevents `A=20` from matching.
- `END{print "Final counter value=",count}`

  This is executed after `awk` has finished with the file.  This simply prints out the result.

#### Working with multiple files one at a time

If there are multiple `.gz` files in the directory and we want to get the count for each of them:

```
for f in *.gz
do
    echo " $f: count=$(zcat "$f" | awk -v RS="-----------\n" '/A=2[ ,\n]/ && /dummy=2[ ,\n]/{count++} END{print count}')"
done
```

#### Finding the grand total over multiple files

To obtain the count for all `.gz` files in the current directory:

```
zcat *.gz | awk -v RS="-----------\n" '/A=2[ ,\n]/ && /dummy=2[ ,\n]/{count++} END{print "Final counter value=",count}'
```

#### Working with multiple counters

Suppose that we also want to count the number of records that do not have `dummy=2` (we will them `other`):

```
$ zcat file.gz | awk -v RS="-----------\n" '/A=2[ ,\n]/ && /dummy=2[ ,\n]/{count++} !/dummy=2[ ,\n]/{other++} END{print "Final counter value=",count, "; other=", other}'
Final counter value= 1 ; other= 1
```

Comment: Thanks John. I am not very familiar with the awk syntax, would you be kind enough to explain it?

Comment: @Java OK.  Explanation added.

Comment: ok I think I got it except why we need to do /A=2[ ,\n] /in the search pattern instead of /A=2/?

Comment: one more question John, In the above awk expression since I have to go through multiple gz files where I would put for loop?

Comment: @Java I added code to handle multiple gzipped files.

Comment: Thanks John. But what if I wanted a grand total( i.e count for all the files)?Also If I understood this clearly in awk the syntax is BEGIN , /SEACRH/ and END.Now If I want some logic based on search like if if dummy=2 increment count but if dummy != 2 increment another variable in which section this logic would go?Thanks in advance for your time for a quick awk introductory session:)

Comment: @Java That is much simpler to do: answer updated with grand total calculation.  I also added an example with two counters.

Comment: John, I added EOE to the end of each record above and when I run cat testme2 | awk '{print "Processing Record - ",NR;}END {print NR, "Records are processed";}' it gives me the right number of records. but adding record seperator gives me incorrect results:cat testme2 | awk -v RS="EOE\n" '{print "Processing Record - ",NR;}END {print NR, "Records are processed";}'.Why is that?